# How to check exist service in module?

Tags: nestjs

I want to check exist service in module.
I have found way by check file in folder.
But, is there a better way?

Comment: Do you just need to know if the service is available in your application at runtime? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to see the module providers

Comment: Okay, you want to see the module's providers. _Why_? What use case are you solving here? Where are you trying to call the code to figure out what exists?